# How to update value to the column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 table called `PROJECTS` and `PROJECTS_EMPLOYEES_RELATIONSHIP` in PostgreSQL database. In first table as you can see I have column called `TOTAL_EMPLOYEES`. In that column I want to store total number of employees in the project based on the information of 2nd table. I tried next sql statement but it raise error. How to fix this error?

**PROJECTS**:

```
| ID (uuid)                             | TOTAL_EMPLOYEES (int) |
|---------------------------------------|-----------------------|
| 36c89a24-fff2-4cbc-a542-b1e956a352f9  | 0                     |
| 41c89a24-fff2-4cbc-a542-b1e956a352f9  | 5                     |
```

**PROJECTS_EMPLOYEES_RELATIONSHIP**:

```
| PROJECT_ID (uuid)                     | EMPLOYEE (varchar)    |
|---------------------------------------|-----------------------|
| 36c89a24-fff2-4cbc-a542-b1e956a352f9  | NNogerbek@gmail.com   |
| 41c89a24-fff2-4cbc-a542-b1e956a352f9  | IKim@gmail.com        |
```

**SQL**:

```
UPDATE PROJECTS
SET TOTAL_EMPLOYEES = COUNT(EMPLOYEE)
FROM PROJECTS
LEFT JOIN PROJECTS_EMPLOYEES_RELATIONSHIP
ON PROJECTS.ID = PROJECTS_EMPLOYEES_RELATIONSHIP.PROJECT_ID
WHERE PROJECTS.ID = PROJECTS_EMPLOYEES_RELATIONSHIP.PROJECT_ID;
```

**ERROR**:

```
SQL Error [42712]: ERROR: table name "PROJECTS" specified more than once.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - see [update join](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/) as reference

```
UPDATE PROJECTS
SET TOTAL_EMPLOYEES = cntemployee 
FROM (SELECT PROJECT_ID, COUNT(EMPLOYEE) AS cntemployee 
      FROM PROJECTS_EMPLOYEES_RELATIONSHIP
      GROUP BY PROJECT_ID) B
WHERE PROJECTS.ID = B.PROJECT_ID
```

Comment: Hello! I tried your code right now. It raise such error: `SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in UPDATE`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek, I've edited it - you can check now